# Regular Expression to extract from string

Tags: regex

I cannot find the way to fetch every string, separated by "-" from string which pattern is like this

some text - some text - wanted text - other wanted text

I only can use regular expressions to match an fetch the wanted data. But i cannot find the regular expressions which extract "wanted text" and "other wanted text

Comment: What logical rules dictate that only the 2nd two tokens are valid?

Comment: what if the input string would be `'some text' - 'some text' - 'wanted text with-hyphen' - 'other wanted text'` ?

Comment: For now the logical rule is the way is typed, so for now its only be the 2nd two tokens. And because is split by "-", the inner "-" it gets replaced for other char, so everytime its going to be 3 "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which language are you using? If you're using Python (for example), you could use a regex like this:

https://regex101.com/r/VKqXWX/1

Will copy here in case the link expires: `[^-]+`

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: For now im using ^(.*)(?= -(.*) -(.*)-) to fetch the first one, (?<= - )(.*)(?= -(.*)-), to fetch the second one, and had problems with the third. I need to extract only one string per regex

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your problem... You have a string, and you want to split it by the `-` character. Isn't that right? My solution does exactly that, but of course there's lots of cases where it just might not be the right solution. It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: The problem is, i need to extract only one portion at time, that means only one string per regex. This is because i cannot use any language to process the result data

Comment: what are you using then?

Comment: It's for vendor web crawling tools, but i think i have to format the fetched data with some language

Comment: My question is: what are you currently doing to crawl?